# Order of evaluation of member initiazation-list in a constructor

Tags: c++, constructor

Constructor member initialization-list order depends on the order of member variable declaration in the class

This is what I read throughout the web....

what is the reason behind such an output of the following code:

```
#include<cstdio>
class A
{
public:
    int a,b,c;
    A(int x,int y,int z) : a(x),b(y),c(z)
    {

    }
    A(int y,int z) : b(y),c(z)
    {

    }
};
int main()
{
    A obj(1,2.3);
    A obj2(1,2);

    printf("%d %d %d\n",obj.a,obj.b,obj.c);
    printf("%d %d %d\n",obj2.a,obj2.b,obj2.c);
}
```

I am expecting:

```
1 2 3
* 1 2
```

But the output is:

```
0 1 2
0 1 2
```

Working example:
http://ideone.com/cw0qLQ

Comment: `A obj(1,2.3);`  um. is that decimal supposed to be there ?? You're invoking the two-param constructor *twice*, right ?

Comment: `a` is not initialized in either object. You shouldn't expect anything in particular. Accessing `a` gives you undefined behaviour.

Comment: Not sure what this has to do with order of operations....you initialize B and C in the two parameter constructor, and pass a two argument decimal into `obj`. So if you did it right and had `A obj(1,2,3); A obj(1,2);` i'd expect `1 2 3\n* 1 2)`

Comment: you're expecting an asterisk? that's interesting...

Comment: The syntax highlighting on ideone shows `2.3` in purple, so it should stick out if it is indeed a typo.

Comment: Please fix the typo 2.3

Comment: mybad.......
misinterpreted decimal point as a comma

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that you are using the second constructor definition for both cases

```
A(int y,int z) : b(y),c(z) {
}
```

The constructor call

```
A obj(1,2.3);
      // ^
```

Has a `double` parameter, that will be converted to `2` automatically. `a` is left uninitialized in both cases.

Comment: no, `a` is not value-initialized in the second case, it is just left un-initialized, and most of the time it happens to be `0`

Comment: Nice catch of a typo

Comment: "and most of the time it happens to be 0", about as often on gcc as I see rainbow-farting unicorns :)

Comment: @JBarberU I was not making a precise and rigorous mathematical statement about the measure of the set where the event is true. However, if you try on most compilers, you will get zero (although again it is UB, so you should not expect zero). At least that's what's happening on my machine and on most online compilers. I guess I see more unicorns than you :)

Comment: Just wanted to point out that it's highly platform dependent. I haven't seen it with either clang or gcc. And besides, it quite useful since those values often stand out.

Answer (score 3):

In both cases, you call constructor

```
A(int y,int z)
```

You may be doing that inadvertently in the case of `obj`, but the end result is that the code doesn't initialize `A::a` in either case.

When you access `obj.a` or `obj2.a` you invoke *undefined behaviour*. You can't expect any particular outcome from your program.

Answer (score 1):

I can see that the ctor function A (int,int) is called in your code, which just initialize y and z and leave x the default value.

Comment: Except there is no default value.